# Modifying object in AfterInsert / AfterUpdate

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object that holds results of a calculation based on parameters that are properties of the same domain object.  I'd like to make sure that any time parameters get changed by the user, it recalculates and gets saved properly into the database.

I am trying to do that with afterInsert (to make sure calculation is correct in the first place), and afterUpdate.

However, since my calculation is trying to modify the object itself, it's not working - throwing various hibernate exceptions.

I tried to put the afterUpdate code into a transaction, but that didn't help.   I am afraid I am getting into a circular dependency issues here.

The exception I am getting right now is:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [esc.scorecard.PropertyScorecard#27]
```

Are the GORM events designed for simpler use cases?  I am tempted to conclude that modifying the object you are in the middle of saving is not the way to go.

Comment: what's your workaround with this problem. I am also facing this dilemma. *.withNewSession* doesn't seem to work for afterInsert. I can't flush the object nor just save it (well i can .save() but it seems that the calculations I've done inside the afterInsert are not persisted in the database if I just use .save() ). thanks! Anyway what I just want to do is to persist a User object inside of my domain class (eg., Message) who created it. Since audit-trail just saves a Long reference only (eg., createdby), I can't eventually manipulate the Message domain class and eventually reference its attrib

Answer (score 3):

Are you using 1.2.0+?

If you are, you can use .withNewSession in the events closures which is supposed to avoid hibernate chaos.

cheers

Lee

Comment: yes, i am on 1.2.1.  I tried using withNewSession, but that didn't help, resulting in weird hibernate errors.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason against using `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` instead of `afterInsert` and `afterUpdate`?

If not, switching to the `before*` event handlers should fix your issue

Comment: I thought by the time afterInsert fires, the object is almost persisted, and has an id by that point, but I might be wrong - the whole persistence process (with events) doesn't seem to be well-documented.

Comment: Indeed, if your calculation is using the 'id' property, it might be a problem to locate your code into before* handlers. And I don't know which event is fired when id is generated.